# OL3 ZoomToExtent Control throws "Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: invalid extent or geometry"

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a map with the following projection specified:

```
proj4.defs( "EPSG:3978", "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs" );
```

If I specify an extent in my control constructor then the map zooms to the given extent. The docs indicate that: "If undefined the validity extent of the view projection is used." Any idea why the extent can't be calculated for the given projection? Is it possible for the extent control to function as intended without specifying an extent?

Answer (score 0):

The Proj4js definition does not contain a validity extent. You have to specify that manually, using `ol.proj.get('EPSG:3978').setExtent(/* extent */)`. You can find the validity extent in online projection databases, like e.g. http://epsg.io/. Look for "Projected bounds" there.

I'm surprised about your question "Is it possible for the extent control to function as intended without specifying an extent?", because its intention is to zoom to a specified extent.